# Upstart: launching something only once

Tags: startup, upstart

Fact: If you use `start on <event>` for a job, your job might be run every time `<event>` occurs.
The [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#guarantee-that-a-job-will-only-run-once) mentions two methods to run a job only once.

The first is logical to me, and involves creating a dummy run-forever job that is started on `<event>`. Since that dummy job is run-forever, and single-instance, it will get started only once and you can use `start on started <dummy-job>` in your actual job.

The second method looks a lot simpler: `start on startup and <event>`. **The purpose of this question is to understand why this second method works**. This has to do with understanding how `on start` handles events compounded by `and`. I.e., since `<event>` occurs multiple times, why is it that the compounded event is triggered only once? Could it be that a compounded event is re-triggered only after **both** `startup` and `<event>` are re-triggered? **I'm looking for a confirmation of this.**

Answer (score 2):

I will share my findings, which give an empirical answer to my question.

I tested using 2 events, `desktop-session-start` and `net-device-up` and indeed it seems that the compounded event `desktop-session-start and net-device-up` is only triggered when each of the events has been triggered.

Specifically, I get the event the first time I log into ubuntu, after the network has come up (dhcp completed). Then if I toggle networking, I don't get the event. Likewise, if I log out/log in, while networking stays connected, I don't get the event. I only get it when I log in **and** networking has been down since last triggering, or analogously, when I bring the interface up after I have logged out, since last triggering.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `event-a and event-b` is only true once BOTH event-a and event-b have been emitted, and if your job runs, then BOTH events have to be emitted again to be true.